# Is there a way to exclude mails in trash from search results in mail?

Tags: macos, email

This is very annoying in mail.

Suppose I am deleting mails with a title "ABC Routers". I search for these emails on mail. Mail shows me a list. I select them and delete. The list is cleared but half a second later they show again because mail found them on the trash folder inside mail.

Is there a way to not show emails that are inside the trash inside a mail account?

Comment: Using a smart mailbox might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mail > Preferences > General.

Make sure that the checkboxes at the bottom reflect where you want to search. If you don't want to search the Trash mailbox, then the Trash checkbox should not be checked.

[image]

Comment: DUUUH! I missed that! Brilliant. thanks!